# QGIS cluster character symbol visibility based on cluster size

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, clustering

I want to display the cluster size with a condition : I don't want to display this information for small clusters.
The expression is working fine but I don't know I can add `else`...

```
case 
when @cluster_size > 30 then @cluster_size
end
```

Is my case, cluster size of the clusters with a size > 30 are displayed. BUT cluster <30 are labelled with a A letter AND I want to display NOTHING.

Not working :

```
case 
when @cluster_size > 30 
then @cluster_size
else @cluster_size = NULL
end
```

Returns me 0 but not empty :

```
case 
when @cluster_size > 30 
then @cluster_size
else @cluster_size = ' '
end
```

If I remove A letter from the assistant, nothing is displayed.

[image]

Comment: What do you want to display in `Else` condition?

Comment: @ahmadhanb  I want to display nothing

Comment: Have you tried `Else NULL`?

Comment: @ahmadhanb not working : `case when @cluster_size > 30 then @cluster_size else @cluster_size = NULL end`

Comment: I think it should be just `''` to display empty text instead of `NULL`

Comment: @ahmadhanb then 0 is displayed and not " "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what is wrong in your case but I can confirm that `Else ''` removed the `A` and got empty cluster:

```
case 
when @cluster_size > 30 then @cluster_size
else ''
end
```

[image]

Output

[image]

I am using QGIS 3.10.4.

Comment: I used wrong syntax